# How do I export WordPress posts and comments... in an alternative way?

Tags: xml, wordpress

my mom's blog after 10 years of writing (so manual copying is close to impossible) has been moved by its platform provider to WordPress. We'd like to use our own WordPress instance, but provider of the old one made WordPress unusable by disabling loads of options, so we neither can use default export option nor use a plugin to do so.

How do I generate XML in this blocked WordPress instance so I could move all the data on our own WordPress instance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have access to the underlying database, you can pull a MySQL dump and reconstitute it on your own machine. Then you could change the options and/or export as XML. If you don't have db access though, you might be forced to use something like wget or curl to crawl the pages. Then at least you'd have XHTML files.

Comment: Check the feeds of the site too: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Comment: Can you modify theme? Is theme editor accessible? If so, there is an way.